# Select columns in Mysql like an array of multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have tables for example called 'city':

`+-----+---------------------+
| id  | name                |
+-----+---------------------+
|   2 | Amsterdam           |
|   3 | The Hague           |
|   8 | Barcelona           |
|  10 | Rome                |
|  11 | Paris               |
|  12 | Rotterdam           |`

I need to select columns information in this format:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [Amsterdam] => 2
          [The_Hague] => 3
          ...
      )
)
```

I do not want to select the information like, and mapping that information to needed format:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [title] => Amsterdam
          [value] => 2
      )
  [1] => Array
      (
          [title] => The_Hague
          [value] => 3
      )
)
```

Can I do it by using concat, json or something else?

Comment: What are those 2, 3 values in the PHP array ?

Comment: it is ID of city

Comment: SELECT city.id as value, city.name as title FROM city;

Comment: *"I know how to make it with PHP, I think maybe I can do it only with MySQL query –"* But No You can't do it only in MySQL as MySQL SQL dialect does not support the ANSI/ISO SQL standard where `ARRAY` datatype is a thing..

Comment: But MySQL can construct JSON data with native JSON functions which MySQL version do you have? -> `SELECT VERION()`

Comment: SELECT VERSION() - 5.5.62

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using PHP. If so, you can do this:

```
    /* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I know how to make it with PHP, I think maybe I can do it only with MySQL query